# Print all the files which are at maximum depth in a directory

Tags: awk

Print all the files which are present in maximum depth 
for example

```
abc/1/2/3/4/r.txt
abc/1/f1.txt
abc/11/22/44/66/77/f2.txt
abc/11/22/44/66/77/f4.txt
abc/11/22/44/66/77/f5.txt
```

so this would print

```
abc/11/22/44/66/77/f2.txt
abc/11/22/44/66/77/f4.txt
abc/11/22/44/66/77/f5.txt
```

I have written this command

```
$cat listoffiles.txt  | awk -F "/" ' { if ( NF > x ) { x = NF; y = $0 } }END{ print y }'
```

but this is printing only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Keep buffering deepest files and discard them whenever the max depth changes. At the end, dump what's in the buffer.

```
awk -F'/+' 'NF>max{max=NF;delete buf} NF==max{buf[$0]} END{for(f in buf) print f}' file
```